Form in Laravel doesn't trigger the `store()` method in the controller and reloads the page without errors
I’m developing a Laravel 10 application where users can add stages to a trip. I have a form in the travel show.blade.php file that allows creating a new stage. When I submit the form, the page reloads, but no new entry is created in the database, and it seems like the store() method in the controller isn’t being executed.
Context:
Form in the Blade file (show.blade.php):
<form action="{{ route('user.stages.store', $travel->slug) }}" method="POST"
        class="add_stage_form w-100 d-none py-3">
        @csrf

        <input type="hidden" name="travel_id" value="{{ $travel->id }}">


        <div class="input_wrapper mb-1 row">
          <label for="place" class="input_label">{{ __('Tappa') }}</label>

          <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="place" type="text" class="form-control @error('place') is-invalid @enderror" name="place"
              value="{{ old('place') }}" required autocomplete="place" autofocus>

            @error('place')
              <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
              </span>
            @enderror
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="input_wrapper mb-3 row">
          <label for="note" class="input_label">{{ __('Note') }}</label>

          <div class="col-md-6">
            <textarea id="note" name="note" class="form-control @error('note') is-invalid @enderror" autofocus>
            {{ old('note') }}
            </textarea>

            @error('note')
              <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
              </span>
            @enderror
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="d-flex align-items-center gap-3">

          <button type="submit" class="btn button_style btn_primary">
            Salva tappa
          </button>

          <button type="button" class="close_form_btn btn button_style btn_secondary">
            Elimina tappa
          </button>

        </div>
      </form>


Controller (StageController.php):
public function store(StoreStageRequest $request, Travel $travel)
{
    // Validate
    $val_data = $request->validated();

    // Set the travel_id
    $val_data['travel_id'] = $travel->id;

    // Create slug
    $slug = Str::slug($request->place, '-');
    $val_data['slug'] = $slug;

    // Handle photo upload if present
    if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {
        $image_path = Storage::put('uploads', $request->file('photo'));
        $val_data['photo'] = $image_path;
    }

    // Create the stage
    Stage::create($val_data);

    dd('Store method reached', $request->all(), $travel);

    // Redirect to the trip's show page
    return redirect()->route('user.travels.show', $travel->slug)->with('message', 'New stage added!');
}


Request Validation Class (StoreStageRequest.php):
public function authorize(): bool
{
    return true;
}

public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        'place' => 'required|min:5|max:150',
        'travel_id' => 'required|exists:travel,id',
        'note' => 'nullable|max:250',
        'photo' => 'nullable|image|max:2000'
    ];
}


When I submit the form:
The page reloads, but no new entry is created in the stages table in the database.
I don’t see the output of the dd() I placed at the beginning of the store() method, which suggests the method isn’t being triggered.
There are no visible errors on the page, and the form seems to be submitted correctly.
Question:
Why isn’t the store() method in the controller being executed, and why does the page reload without saving data to the database? How can I fix this issue and ensure the method is correctly triggered?
Thanks in advance for any help!
What I’ve Tried:

I verified that the POST route is correctly configured in the web.php file:

route::post('/travels/{travel}/stages', [StageController::class, 'store'])->name('stages.store');


I made sure that the CSRF token is present in the form.

I monitored the POST request using the browser’s developer tools and observed that the request is being sent to the correct URL (http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/travels/{slug}/stages) with a status code of 302.



in store method first line do this dd($request->all());    if you find data then remove this live and check dd($val_data) to check your data is validate or not

since you are redirected and the request didnt reach the dd() instruction, then you have a validation error (which "redirects" back before it enters the controller). How are you checking that there are no validation errors as you said "without errors" ? did you use this for it https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors ?

The dd() in ther store method are not executed, in any place of the method.
For the validation error I've added a
@if ($errors->any())
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
          <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
              <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
          </ul>
        </div>
@endif

and when I submit the form I get an error "The field travel_id is required"

N69S is correct; you're validating your input, but you weren't showing the errors anywhere. You're validating the field_id input, but you don't have an <input name="field_id"> anywhere in your form, so your code will never hit your store() method (it's intercepted in your StoreStageRequest and redirected first). You need to either add an <input> for this field_id field, or remove your validation rule. Either way, the code is working exactly as written, and you need to handle this.

Sorry, I just noticed that I pasted the wrong form in the question! I have an hidden input that poi to "travel_id" but I was using the StorageStageRequest class to get the data for the store method, and for some reason this did not work.

Ah, gotcha; it happens. Still, using <input type="hidden" name="travel_id" value="{{ $travel->id }}"> and getting the error "The field travel_id is required" is... Odd, unless $travel->id is null, which if $travel is a Model instance, should never be the case. Or, maybe it was exists:travel,id that failed; is your table name travel or travels? I'd expect a SQL error if that was a typo... So all around, odd set of circumstances. Regardless, glad it got it sorted out!

You dont need to validate the presence of travel_id since you are using the slug present in route to identify the Travel in question and if not present or the Travel is not existing in the DB, a 404 will be triggered.
So, just remove the travel_id from validation if you are not using StoreStageRequest::class anywhere else.
If you are using it somewhere else, it's better to make a new Form Requests Class without travel_id rules

Thank you N69S it works! I have deleted the validation in the StorageStageRequest and took the data for the store method from the input. I don't kwon if I can validate the data in this way without the StorareStageRequest... I think I can but I have to figure out how! Anyway, thank you!

I think there might be an issue with the action within your form..
Do something like this
action="{{ route('stages.store', $travel->slug) }}" 

then in the store method dry dump the request
dd($request->all());

If it shows the debug information then congrats the method is executed well..
Then check your submitted values like
dd($request->text);
dd($request->note);



Thanks for the reply, but the action that you suggested does not work since my routes are prefixed with "user" so the correct name is "user.stages.store".
